# How to properly run my project using GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, torch

I am really new to torch and machine learning. I am trying to run my project using GPU. I tried to have such modification to my code:

```
model = Challenge()
    model = model.to(torch.device('cuda'))
```

However, I am still having following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ruidong/Desktop/YZR temp/Project2/train_challenge.py", line 112, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/ruidong/Desktop/YZR temp/Project2/train_challenge.py", line 91, in main
    stats)
  File "C:/Users/ruidong/Desktop/YZR temp/Project2/train_challenge.py", line 40, in _evaluate_epoch
    output = model(X)
  File "C:\Users\ruidong\Anaconda3\envs\EECS445\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ruidong\Desktop\YZR temp\Project2\model\challenge.py", line 48, in forward
    z = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
  File "C:\Users\ruidong\Anaconda3\envs\EECS445\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ruidong\Anaconda3\envs\EECS445\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 345, in forward
    return self.conv2d_forward(input, self.weight)
  File "C:\Users\ruidong\Anaconda3\envs\EECS445\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 342, in conv2d_forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: Expected object of device type cuda but got device type cpu for argument #1 'self' in call to _thnn_conv2d_forward
```

Any suggestions? really appreciate.

Comment: Now the project can run, but still doesn't use GPU. I am so confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is correctly moved to GPU. However, for a model that is placed in GPU, you need to pass the tensors that are in GPU too. The error is because you are passing tensor that is placed in CPU in a model that is in GPU. Just do the same for inputs before passing them to model

Comment: Thank you Marzieh! I just did the same thing for the inputs. The program can run now. But it still doesn't seem to use my GPU cuz the speed didn't improve much. Any ideas? Thank you again

Comment: @JimYang You can monitor your GPU usage in the windows task manager. Verify that the GPU utilization increases when running your code. If your model or dataset are very small then the additional overhead of transferring to/from the GPU may be greater than the computational benefit.